# Get Quarter and Year between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'd like to retrieve the list of years and quarters between two dates.

For example, from 25/12/2015 to 06/30/2017, the result should look like:

```
Year    Quarter

2015    4
2016    1
2016    2
2016    3
2016    4
2017    1
2017    2
2017    3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a tally table to do this.

```
declare @start date='2015-12-25';
declare @end date = '2017-06-30';

select distinct year(dateadd(day,rnum,@start)) yr,
datepart(quarter,dateadd(day,rnum,@start)) qtr
from (select row_number() over(order by (select null)) as rnum 
      from master..spt_values) t
where dateadd(day,rnum,@start) <= @end;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to span more than 6 years... virtually identical to vkp (he's so fast!)

```
Declare @Date1 date = '2015-12-25'
Declare @Date2 date = '2017-06-30'

Select Distinct 
       [Year]   =DatePart(YEAR,D)
      ,[Quarter]=DatePart(QUARTER,D)
 From (
        Select Top (DateDiff(DD,@Date1,@Date2)+1) D=DateAdd(DAY,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)),@Date1) 
         From  master..spt_values n1,master..spt_values n2
      ) A
```

**Returns**

```
Year    Quarter
2015    4
2016    1
2016    2
2016    3
2016    4
2017    1
2017    2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @StartDate Date='2016-01-01'
      , @EndDate Date='2017-05-01'

DECLARE @Date TABLE
(
    [Year] INT,
    [Quarter] INT
)

WHILE @StartDate <= @EndDate
BEGIN   
    INSERT INTO @Date 
    ([Year],
     [Quarter])

SELECT DATEPART(YEAR,@StartDate) AS [Year],
       CASE WHEN DATEPART(MM,@StartDate) BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN 1
            WHEN DATEPART(MM,@StartDate) BETWEEN 4 AND 6 THEN 2
            WHEN DATEPART(MM,@StartDate) BETWEEN 7 AND 9 THEN 3
            WHEN DATEPART(MM,@StartDate) BETWEEN 10 AND 12 THEN 4
        END AS [Quarter]
SET     @StartDate = DATEADD(DAY,1,@StartDate)   
END

SELECT DISTINCT [Year],[Quarter] FROM @Date
```